# Accounts in serverside JavaScript (node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, database, node.js

I'm making an online game and I was wondering - how can users create accounts? Do I need a database, and if yes, which one? Also how do I get information from the users? I believe by using html  tag, but how exactly? I'm not using PHP for the serverside, but node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many answers to this question it's tough to begin at one place.

I'll just suggest some technologies because that seems to be what you're looking for. Ultimately I recommend you research this area and make up your own mind on what you'd like to use.

You can use a database to store the user information. NoSQL is popular nowadays so I'll go for a `MongoDB` solution http://www.mongodb.org/

You don't exactly need to use HTML tags as there are template solutions written for node.js. I recommend `jade` https://github.com/visionmedia/jade

There are frameworks and middleware created to make all of this easier. Check it out here https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but databases seem a little bit too complicated, can't I just create a file that contains all the passwords and usernames along with the information?

Comment: @bane You certainly can, but you may not want to. Take a look, for example, at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356851/database-vs-flat-files) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392017/sqlite-or-flat-text-file) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499239/database-vs-flat-text-file-what-are-some-technical-reasons-for-choosing-one-over), etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292477/node-says-jade-has-no-method-renderfile-why

Take a look at this question please, I have some problems with Jade.

Comment: Nothing wrong with flat files. As of node v0.5.x you can require JSON files so having a quick and easy JSON store may be a good solution. There's more flexibility with a database though so you may want to consider that.