# Is there a way to get the HTML of a JADE Template before sending it via response

Tags: node.js, express, pug

What I usually do is:

```
res.render('myJadeTemplate');
```

but I want to add another transformation to the html before attaching it to the response.

How can I get the rendered HTML then modify it and send it over via `res.send()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Express3. There is an additional (and optional) parameter to [`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render) that is a callback that will give you the rendered HTML rather than sending it directly to the client.

```
res.render('myJadeTemplate', function (err, html) {
    // html => rendered HTML from jade template
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a solution:

```
    var jade = require('jade');
var fs = require('fs');

var jadetemplate = jade.compile(fs.readFileSync('code.jade', 'utf8'));

var html = jadetemplate({
 params:"{Some parames}"
});

console.log(html);
```

Thanks for this thread
[Node says Jade has no method "renderFile", why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292477/node-says-jade-has-no-method-renderfile-why)